# k8s-hub image not valid when created from docker build -f Dockerfile -t k8s-hub:0.8.2

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, jupyterhub

What I did:

1. Downloaded repo

   ```sh
   git clone https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s
   ```
2. checkout'd the 0.8.2 tag

   ```sh
   git fetch --all --tags --prune
   git tag
   git checkout tags/0.8.2
   git status
   HEAD detached at 0.8.2
   ```
3. Did a Docker build of the Docker image

   ```sh
   docker build -f Dockerfile -t k8s-hub:0.8.2 .
   ```
4. Did a docker images

   ```sh
   docker images
   REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             
   SIZE
   k8s-hub             0.8.2               439891eafce8        3 minutes ago       534MB
   ubuntu              18.04               d27b9ffc5667        45 hours ago        64.2MB
   ```
5. Results:

   The image is not functional. Errors while building

   ```sh
   ... 

   Get:98 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 sqlite3 amd64 3.22.0-1ubuntu0.4 [752 kB]
   debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
   Fetched 114 MB in 9s (13.4 MB/s)
   ...
   Setting up patch (2.7.6-2ubuntu1.1) ...
   Setting up xz-utils (5.2.2-1.3) ...
   update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/xz to provide /usr/bin/lzma (lzma) in auto mode
   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzma.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xz.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/unlzma.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/unxz.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzcat.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzcat.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzmore.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzmore.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzless.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzless.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzdiff.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzdiff.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzcmp.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzcmp.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzgrep.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzgrep.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzegrep.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzegrep.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
   update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzfgrep.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzfgrep.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
   Setting up libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64 (7.5.0+dfsg-1) ...
   ```
6. Need an image similar to: 
   https://hub.docker.com/layers/jupyterhub/k8s-hub/0.8.2/images/sha256-0492ebf6917e3da9a8c8ce35d4e014769f469271b724a58b0823cba7bee066ce?context=explore

   When downloaded looks like this:

   ```sh
   docker images
   REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
   jupyterhub/k8s-hub   0.8.2               e48e1e021139        15 months ago       558MB
   ```

Comment: The `update-alternatives` warnings seem harmless. How do you conclude that it's broken?

Comment: It is the wrong size when compared to image in #6 and the image will not deploy to kubernetes. when I download the image from dockerhub it looks like this.    docker images
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jupyterhub/k8s-hub   0.8.2               e48e1e021139        15 months ago       558MB

Comment: The size difference seems to be easily explained by the `sqlite3` version number; the paokage has received four updates of which probably several were issued in the last year, so you are building with a different version. I haven't looked at your other dependencies, but there are probably other packages with a similar scenario. If you want exactly that image from 15 months ago, simply pull exactly that image instead of building your own.

Comment: Pulling the image is not an option due to our security rules. I will test the image further though. I did do a checkout of the branch before compiling. git checkout tags/0.8.2

Comment: @tripleee You were right. My deployment script was wrong. The image works fine.

Comment: Weird security rules if they allow you to download arbitrary Debian packages but not a Docker image.